# Session timeout server push on Torquebox2

Tags: jboss, jruby, jrubyonrails, torquebox

I want to notify the browser side via javascript about an approaching session timeout.

My current implementation polls a URL every so often to find out if X seconds remain until session timeout.

For purely academic scaling reasons, what is an alternative to polling for session timeout on a Torquebox2 environment?

For example if I use a websocket server, how do I add session timeout information for the user and is it possible to have the client side trigger immediately after the information is pushed?

Is there a simple gem or alternative that does the bulk of work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web sockets would surely be better than polling.

There is a good example of web socket usage in torquebox here https://github.com/torquebox/stomp-chat-demo

In this example, session information is set and read both in the Sinatra application and in the stomplets (analogous to an http controller but for web sockets).  The documentation for web sockets in TorqueBox shows how to use the session both in your application controller and your stomplet here http://torquebox.org/documentation/current/stomp.html#d0e3602

Comment: Thanks, I saw the demo, but I was mainly interested in performance and security. It seems like in that demo anyone would be able to edit some javascript and add himself to the public roster as someone else. So the security is up to me to uphold. (using csrf meta tags, perhaps?)

Comment: One of the nice things about how TorqueBox exposes websockets is it uses Stomplets which you can think of as controllers in the MVC sense. When a connection is made, or a message is sent from the browser, the web session is included as a part of the request. This gives you an opportunity to handle authentication at the web layer (where it arguably belongs), and your stomplet can just check the session to see if the request has been authenticated.